# C# App.Config File Path combine

Tags: c#, methods, app-config, filepath

I'm trying without success to use app.config keys with file path based.

This is my App.Config:

```
<appSettings>

<add key="States" value="NY,CA,MA" />
<add key="SourceFile_NY" value="C:\NY\file.xlsx" />
<add key="SourceFile_CA" value="C:\CA\file.xlsx" />
<add key="SourceFile_MA" value="C:\MA\file.xlsx" />
```

Now, on the main class, i'd like to obtain the file for each state given:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var states = "NY,CA,MA".Split(',');

        foreach (var state in states)
        {

            new SomeMethodFromOtherClass().class(SourceFile_ + XX);


        }

    }
```

I'm trying to get the file path based on the state on the **SourceFile_ + XX** part, but i can't find any good way to accomplish the call to the app.config value for each state

Comment: Are you capturing a user input to determine which file to load?

Comment: Not for now, i just have the files already on the server.

Comment: Are you going to have to load one file only? Or all the files and use them?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add a reference in your project to `System.Configuration`.

Then you just do:

```
var ny = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[sourcefile + "_NY"];
```

Comment: Thank you, that's usefull, but how do i assign that var value on the specific  iteration of the foreach? In other words, when the foreach item value is 'CA', how do i assign the value [sourcefile + "_CA"]; inside the class parameter?

Comment: I really can't discern what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I want to dynamically change the source file based on the state (Item). If the state is NY, the file source path should be 'SourceFile_NY', if the state is CA, the file source path should be 'SourceFile_CA', and so on.